# Why I can't test for FileNotFoundException in java JUnit 4.13

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, filenotfoundexception

I am facing some difficulties with testing constructor of my class using JUnit 4.13. What I am trying to do is to test that constructor is throwing FileNotFoundExeption when I pass wrong file name.

This is my constructor (parameter 'file' is name of file where I store languages):

```java
public LanguageManager(String file) {
        this.languages = new ArrayList<Language>();
        
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "utf-8"));
            String line;
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.trim();
                if (line.equals("") || line.startsWith("#"))
                    continue;
                Language j = new Language(line);
                this.languages.add(j);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is my function for testing this constructor:

```
@Test(expected=FileNotFoundException.class)
    public void testLanguageManager() {
        LanguageManager ajm = new LanguageManager("non_existing_file.txt");
    }
```

I suspect that there is problem with try catch block in constructor but can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If the exception is being captured inside constructor the caller class will not have a way to know what happens. To achieve that the exception should be thrown from constructor so you can capture exception from the test.

Comment: So I shoudn't print stack but throw e?

Comment: You shouldn’t have the try and catch blocks at all.

Comment: Short answer, yes. If you know a constructor can throw an exception then you'll try control possible errores associated with this. If this is done in the constructor of the instantiated class then you dont need to worry  about a exception that will never happen